# Send a .txt file with StreamWriter

Tags: c#

I want to send some stuff to some server, I want to use `StreamWriter`, to write some strings on the streamwriter it's easy, suppose I want also to send to `.txt` file how can I do that?

Here is example of what I need:

```
string s="some string";
string path=@"d:\myFile.txt";
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestToServer.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(s);
    streamWriter.Write(path);//<---- I want something like this
}
```

Comment: The framework isn't going to open and read the file for you. You'll need to do that yourself so you have data to send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
streamWriter.Write(File.ReadAllText(path));
```

**EDIT:** Update to question in the comments:

---

*Method 1* by using the current `StreamWriter`:

```
streamWriter.Write(System.Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(path)));
```

and on the server:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path, System.Convert.FromBase64String(textFromClient));
```

---

*Method 2* using the stream directly:

```
var requestStream = requestToServer.GetRequestStream();
using (var inputStream = File.OpenRead(path))
    inputStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
```

Comment: do you know how to do the same for `.docx`?

Comment: @Flufy To send it as a binary stream to get the same document on the server or just the text out of it?

Comment: The same document on the server